# Split up line in columns in matlab

Tags: matlab, file

I have a data file named ***robot4_motors.txt***

The data that it holds is like that

```
M 524 20795 20794 3000 0 16067 16066 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 735 20795 20795 3000 0 16067 16066 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 995 20795 20795 3000 0 16067 16067 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 995 20795 20795 3000 0 16067 16067 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 1233 20795 20795 3000 0 16067 16067 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 1499 20795 20795 3000 0 16067 16067 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 1763 20795 20795 3000 0 16067 16067 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 1763 20795 20795 3000 0 16067 16067 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 2025 20795 20795 3000 0 16067 16066 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 2276 20795 20795 3000 0 16067 16066 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 2533 20795 20794 3000 0 16067 16067 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 2533 20795 20794 3000 0 16067 16067 3000 0 0 0 6000 0
M 2834 20866 20857 3000 500 16138 16129 3000 500 0 0 6000 0
M 3084 20993 20994 3000 500 16265 16267 3000 500 0 0 6000 0
M 3300 21122 21124 3000 500 16393 16395 3000 500 0 0 6000 0
M 3548 21251 21252 3000 500 16522 16523 3000 500 0 0 6000 0
M 3548 21251 21252 3000 500 16522 16523 3000 500 0 0 6000 0
```

and so on. Now I want to split up the line in columns

```
f = fopen('robot4_motors.txt');
tline = fgetl(f); 
while ischar(tline)
    tline = fgetl(f);
    C=strsplit(tline)
    disp(C)
end
fclose(f);
```

This code gives me the right output for the 1st few lines then it throws an error.

> Error using strsplit (line 80) First input must be either a character
>   vector or a string scalar.
>
> Error in trick (line 8)
>       C=strsplit(tline)

What will be the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what your code does in the first pass through the loop:

```
tline = fgetl(f);     % Read in 1st line
while ischar(tline)   % Make sure it's a char array
    tline = fgetl(f); % Discard 1st line, get 2nd line
    C=strsplit(tline) % Work with the line
    disp(C)           % Display the line
end                   % Go back to while...
```

At the end of the loop, you go back to the `while` statement, of course, where you check that the line you just processed is, in fact, a string. You then read in a new line and process it. That is, every time you first process the line, then check that it was a string. Additionally, you never process the first line read from the file. You need to reverse these tests. One way to do so is:

```
tline = fgetl(f); 
while ischar(tline)
    C=strsplit(tline)
    disp(C)
    tline = fgetl(f);
end
```

Here, you test that the line is a string, process it, then read a new one, then test it's a string, etc.

A nicer way to write the same loop is:

```
while 1
    tline = fgetl(f);
    if ~ischar(tline), break, end
    C=strsplit(tline)
    disp(C)
end
```

Here you don't need to repeat the `fgetl` line, and the order of things is a bit clearer: you read a line, you test it, then you print it. The `while 1` is an infinite loop, you break out of it with `break`.